# How can I recover an abandoned US bank account?

Tags: united-states, bank-account, federal-reserve

I have had problems to find out where, at which American bank,  a company I worked for had deposited commission cash and given custody of some shares I purchased through options. But now that I found out they claim that it was donated to the fed because I had abandoned the account (didn't contact in more than 3 years). But the problem was that I didn't know where to look.

Is there a way to recover the money/assets?

Please note that I live in Europe.

Comment: Shares wouldn't be held in a bank account. Could you elaborate on the arrangement you were participating in? Do you know the original broker where your shares were on account? Were the shares of a public company?

Comment: I don't know what's the original broker but could eventually try to find out. Yes, the shares where originally from lucent technologies. Is there a way to recover this?

Answer (score 3):

If the financial institution is no longer active, try the unclaimed funds site:

[image: FDIC unclaimed funds website]

Otherwise, cross-referencing your name across several databases is necessary:

[image: bureau of the fiscal service website]

**References**

- [Bureau of the Fiscal Service - Unclaimed Assets](https://fiscal.treasury.gov/unclaimed-assets.html)
- [Unclaimed Money from the Government | USAGov](https://www.usa.gov/unclaimed-money)
- [Free, Official Sources to Find Unclaimed Money | USAGov](https://www.usa.gov/features/free-official-sources-to-find-unclaimed-money)
- [FDIC: Unclaimed Property Information by State](https://www.fdic.gov/bank/individual/failed/unclaimed-property-states.html)